# Probability Game Question

Tags: probability-theory

I am new to probability. I am trying to solve the following problem.

In a game, probability of winning the game is $w$ & losing the game is $l$ & probability of game continuing is $(1 - w - l)$. What is the probability of winning the game in $m$ steps ?

I know the answer. It is p$(m) = w + (1 - w - l) * p(m - 1).$ Can some one explain why it is.

Comment: Do you mean winning in *exactly* $m$ steps or less than or equal to $m$ steps?

Comment: Its atmost m steps

Answer (score 4):

Let's split the event "winning in at most $m$ steps" as follows: either winning now (assuming we haven't played $m$ turns yet), or continuing the game, and winning in at most $m-1$ steps, starting from the next step.

Now, the two latter events are disjoint, since winning now excludes the game continuing, and vice-verse. Therefore:

$$\Pr(\text{winning in at most $m$ steps})=\Pr(\text{winning now})+\Pr(\text{continuing the game, and winning in at most $m-1$ steps})$$

We know that $\Pr(\text{winning now})=w$, it remains to analyze the second part.
The probability of continuing the game is $1-w-l$. The probability of winning the game in at most $m-1$ steps, *given* that the game is continued, is $p(m-1)$, since $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$, we get that 
$$\Pr(\text{continuing the game, and winning in at most $m-1$ steps})=(1-w-l)\cdot p(m-1)$$, which concludes the result.

It is important to remark that you need to add $p(1)=w$ in order for this recursive definition to be sound.